# How to solve this problem of architecture and scalability?

Tags: computer-architecture, software-engineering

I know this question may seem weird, mainly, why the context (OS, kind of system, etc) isn't explicit. I am studying for an exam, and, according to the studies guide, one of the questions types can be:

"Assuming that a system has a large volume of access, and has a restricted capacity of devices. What difficulties would we face?
How could we get around them?"

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Surely you can give some examples of problems that would be caused by making lots of accesses to a low-powered server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access cost to devices may be high, so caching and/or request coalescing may be employed to maximize the benefit of access while minimizing the cost.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We're looking for answers that are more detailed than this. However, this question is essentially somebody trying to get us to do his homework for him, and this kind of question should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, @FluxIX, All I needed was a starting idea, your answer is enough.